# Wildcard in DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, parsing, java-time

I need to parse a string into a `LocalDate`. The string looks like `31.* 03 2016` in regex terms (i.e. `.*` means that there may be 0 or more unknown characters after the day number).

Example input/output: `31xy 03 2016` ==> `2016-03-31`

I was hoping to find a wildcard syntax in the DateTimeFormatter documentation to allow a pattern such as:

```
LocalDate.parse("31xy 03 2016", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd[.*] MM yyyy"));
```

but I could not find anything.

**Is there a simple way to express optional unknown characters with a `DateTimeFormatter`?**

ps: I can obviously modify the string before parsing it but that's not what I'm asking for.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to preprocess the string before you pass it to the `DateTimeFormatter`? Something else you can do is create your own class which extends `DateTimeFormatter` and override the `ofPattern()` method, but this doesn't seem advisable.

Comment: I would prefer an elegant solution with DateTimeFormatter - if it doesn't exist I'll go for plan B. DateTimeFormatter is final so is not extendable.

Comment: Ah was not aware of that, good to know!

Comment: Please define what is "simple" for you. Is it a pattern-based solution where the char * stands for any count of chars respecting the minimum of pattern widths left, or is a builder-supported approach fine for you?

Comment: @MenoHochschild using a builder is fine

Comment: I have taken your requirement into consideration and can offer a solution based on my lib Time4J (with coming next release v4.14 which will be published still this month), see also this [commit](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/commit/56a95ca8207b69179f83609ddf5537aec2bcc877). If you have any questions or need for clarifications please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct support for this in `java.time`.

The closest would be to use [parse(CharSequence,ParsePosition)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.text.ParsePosition-) using two different formatters.

```
// create the formatter for the first half
DateTimeFormatter a = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd")

// setup a ParsePosition to keep track of where we are in the parse
ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition();

// parse the date, which will update the index in the ParsePosition
String str = "31xy 03 2016";
int dom = a.parse(str, pp).get(DAY_OF_MONTH);

// some logic to skip the messy 'xy' part
// logic must update the ParsePosition to the start of the month section
pp.setIndex(???)

// use the parsed day-of-month in the formatter for the month and year
DateTimeFormatter b = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM yyyy")
    .parseDefaulting(DAY_OF_MONTH, dom);

// parse the date, using the *same* ParsePosition
LocalDate date = b.parse(str, pp).query(LocalDate::from);
```

While the above is untested it should basically work. However, it would be far easier parse it manually.

Comment: Maybe a "lenient" parser that would just skip the unparseable characters? (Using a LENIENT resolver style does not work)

Answer (score 4):

I’d do it in two steps, use a regexp to get the original string into something that LocalDate can parse, for example:

```
String dateSource = "31xy 03 2016";
String normalizedDate = dateSource.replaceFirst("^(\\d+).*? (\\d+ \\d+)", "$1 $2");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(normalizedDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MM yyyy"));
System.out.println(date);
```

I know it’s not what you asked for.

Comment: You can't always get what you want.  But if you try sometimes, well you might find you get what you need.