# Java 8 ISO 8601 Interval syntax with wildcard field(s)

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I need to parse a time interval expression similar to ISO 8601 syntax, only allowing wildcard for fields; and storing the start and end into two `LocalDateTime` objects. My `Interval` would then have APIs to compare to a third `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` to check if it falls inside or outside of the interval.

E.g.: when parsing `"****-**-**T00:00:00Z/****-**-**T11:55:00Z"`, the date of the start and end instant should be the day of the start program execution (ignoring running into the next day problem). How can I parse an expression like this?

EDIT: to make it clear, if I run it today, it should be equivalent of parsing `"2016-04-06T00:00:00Z/2016-04-06T11:55:00Z"`.

Comment: Unclear. Is the String actually `"****-**-**T00:00:00Z/****-**-**T11:55:00Z"`? What do you want the result to be?

Comment: @Tunaki, I thought the example was clear, but added more details now.

Comment: Okay but what is the result you want? To store those two datetime into two `LocalDateTime`? Calculate the period between those two dates?

Comment: I see where the confusion is now. Yes, I would store both start and end into LocalDateTime.

Comment: I still don't understand _only allowing wildcard for fields_.  If you have `"2016-04-06T00:00:00Z/2016-04-06T11:55:00Z"`, just split on the `/` and parse the dates individually.

Comment: @Pillar, I don't have the string `"2016-04-06T00:00:00Z/2016-04-06T11:55:00Z"`, I only have `"****-**-**T00:00:00Z/****-**-**T11:55:00Z"`.

Comment: On program start, save the time. Extract the part after the `T` in your expression and parse it as a time type.

Comment: That won't work for any wildcard field, e.g. `"****-04-01T00:00:00Z/****-04-06T11:55:00Z"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way [to use wildcards when parsing a string with `java.time`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063371/wildcard-in-datetimeformatter). A not so good-looking hack would be to replace the `*` by `1`: that should not produce any unparseable date. You can then ignore the date content.

For example:

```
String input = "****-**-01T00:00:00Z/****-04-**T11:55:00Z";
String[] dates = input.replace("*", "1").split("/");
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(dates[0]);
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(dates[1]);

LocalDate day = LocalDate.now(); //or whatever date you like

LocalDateTime start = zdt1.toLocalTime().atDate(day);
LocalDateTime end = zdt2.toLocalTime().atDate(day);

System.out.println(start + " / " + end);
```