# Including wildcard in a SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, regex, simpledateformat

I want a DateFormatter in java so that i can specify some special character as well as digits in a date expression. For ex :

```
String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz";
```

Here dd is used to specify the day of month which is numeric.
But i have a requirement to create a date as below :

```
 String stringDate = "2017-12-??T00:00Z";
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
 formatter.parse(stringDate);
```

I get an unparseable exception as the DAY specified here is ?? . Is there any workaround for this or shall i have to write a new parser ?

Thanks

Comment: `formatter.parse(stringDate)` returns a `java.util.Date` type.
What is the expected Day value if you missed day value as `??`.

Comment: ?? is used to specify that any day of month december and year 2012. Thats the purpose i want to achieve but simpledatformat isnt allowing this as it expects a numeric value for 'dd'.

Comment: maybe you should use [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html)

Comment: @NathanHughes that exactly what i am asking..so it means i need to write up my own parser which can accept ?? as well.

Comment: @jayendrabhatt @NathanHughes this should word `String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-'??T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"; String stringDate = "2017-12-??T12:08:56.235"; Date date = formatter.parse(stringDate);` But result `date` will be `Fri Dec 01 12:08:56 CET 2017`. So, it set the day value to `01` as default.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I challenge your requirement. `2017-12-23T00:00Z` would be [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), the advantage being that it’s standard, so many software components and many people will read and write it easily. `2017-12-??T00:00Z` does not follow any standard, so hasn’t got any advantage at all. If you cannot fit your real requirements to ISO 8601, don’t just invent your own parser — invent your own format that suits your situation better.

Comment: And please explain in what situation you need a year, a month, a time of day and a UTC offset (of zero), but no day of month? Asking because (1) it leaves me wondering (2) if we understand, I think we can guide you still better than we would do by simply answering the question as asked.

Comment: @OleV.V. As you highlighted this is a ISO 8601 format and rightly so , but this date format is configurable and can be anything as the user wishes to use (in case of my product) . The requirement is to be able to execute a request on each day of Month-December(12) and Year 2017. Similarly it can be every year on christmas- for that the format will be something like ????-12-25,which a user is sending and i need to process this .Thats why i felt i need to write up my own parser. I hope you got me.

Comment: Relatred: [Java 8 ISO 8601 Interval syntax with wildcard field(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456242/java-8-iso-8601-interval-syntax-with-wildcard-fields)

Answer (score 4):

Try escaping the additional literals using single quote

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-'??T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
```

Also the value and the format given should match(Can edit the string date as required), in your case following syntax will work.

```
String stringDate = "2017-12-??T00:00Z";
Date date = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-'??T'HH:mmZ")).parse(stringDate.replaceAll("Z$", "+0000"));
System.out.println("date: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'??T'HH:mmZ")).format(date));
```

Please note that 'Z' indicates that the timezone conforms to the RFC 822 time zone standard as well.

Comment: `replaceAll` is not needed, just use ISO time zone format `'X'` (which should also parse RFC822 time zones)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Consider a scheduler.** Your comment may sound like what you need is a scheduler, for example Quartz scheduler. I include a link at the bottom. Then convert user input not to a `YearMonth`, `OffsetDateTime` or any other date-time object (because they don’t fit), but into a syntax that your scheduler can accept.

**Original answer**

I am giving you a couple of suggestions. It’s with reservation though: I don’t understand why you want this, not even exactly what you want, so these suggestions may not be the right ones for you.

One suggestion I am pretty sure of, though: do use java.time, the modern java date and time API, for your date and time work. It is so much nicer to work with than the old, poorly designed and long outdated date-time classes that include the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class.

**Parsing year and month:** If you just want the year and the month from a string that has question marks instead of the day of  month, parse into a `YearMonth`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-'??T'HH:mmX");

    String stringDate = "2017-12-??T00:00Z";
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse(stringDate, formatter);
    System.out.println("Year and month are " + ym);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> Year and month are 2017-12
> ```

**Parsing all information from the string:** If you need time of day and offset from the same string too, just parse the string once and get the various information from the parse result:

```
    TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parse(stringDate);
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from(parsed);
    System.out.println("Year and month are " + ym);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(parsed);
    System.out.println("Time of day is " + time);
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.from(parsed);
    System.out.println("UTC offset is " + offset);
```

> ```
> Year and month are 2017-12
> Time of day is 00:00
> UTC offset is Z
> ```

**Using a default day of month:** If you know what day of month you want instead of the question marks, specify it as a default value:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-'??T'HH:mmX")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23)
            .toFormatter();
    String stringDate = "2017-12-??T00:00Z";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(stringDate, formatter);
    System.out.println("Date and time is " + dateTime);
```

> ```
> Date and time is 2017-12-23T00:00Z
> ```

**Accepting both numbers and question marks:** If the date can be given as either numeric or question marks, use optional parts in the format pattern strings. Such are enclosed in square brackets:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-[??][dd]'T'HH:mmX")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23)
            .toFormatter();
    String stringDate = "2017-12-??T00:00Z";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(stringDate, formatter);
    System.out.println("Date and time is " + dateTime);
    stringDate = "2018-02-16T00:00Z";
    dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(stringDate, formatter);
    System.out.println("Date and time is " + dateTime);
```

> ```
> Date and time is 2017-12-23T00:00Z
> Date and time is 2018-02-16T00:00Z
> ```

**Tutorial links**

- [Cron Trigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html) from the Quartz Scheduler documentation.
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.